# C# flushing StreamWriter and a MemoryStream

Tags: c#, flush

I use the following snippet of code, and I'm unsure whether I need to call the `Flush` methods (once on `StreamWriter`, once on `MemoryStream`):

```
    //converts an xsd object to the corresponding xml string, using the UTF8 encoding
    public string Serialize(T t)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);

            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream, encoding))
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (T));
                serializer.Serialize(writer, t);
                writer.Flush();
            }

            memoryStream.Flush();

            return encoding.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

First of all, because the code is inside the `using` block, I think the automatically called dispose method might do this for me. Is this true, or is flushing an entirely different concept?

According to stackoverflow itself:

> *Flush meaning clears all buffers for a stream and causes any buffered data to be written to the underlying device.*

What does that mean in the context of the code above?

Secondly, the flush method of the `MemoryStream` [does nothing according to the api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.flush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so what's up with that? why do we call a method that does nothing?

Comment: You don't have to do Flush(), since you've put "using": Writer/Reader will close their buffers automatically on Close/Dispose. Flush() is useful if you want to load/save temporal results (say half of the stream) and keep up work with the streem(s).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't need to use `Flush` on the `StreamWriter`, as you are disposing it (by having it in a `using` block). When it's disposed, it's automatically flushed and closed.

You don't need to use `Flush` on the `MemoryStream`, as it's not buffering anything that is written to any other source. There is simply nothing to flush anywhere.

The `Flush` method is only present in the `MemoryStream` object because it inherits from the `Stream` class. You can see in the [source code for the `MemoryStream` class](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/memorystream.cs,1a4dcb744a23ba6f) that the `flush` method actually does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

In general Streams will buffer data as it's written (periodically flushing the buffer to the associated device if there is one) because writing to a device, usually a file, is expensive. A MemoryStream writes to RAM so the whole concept of buffering and flushing is redundant. The data is always in RAM already.

And yes, disposing the stream will cause it to be flushed.

Answer (score 0):

Commenting flush method returning empty byte[], Though I am Using Using block

```
     byte[] filecontent = null;
        using var ms = new MemoryStream();
        using var sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
        sw.WriteCSVLine(new[] { "A", "B" });//This is extension to write as CSV
        //tx.Flush();
        //fs.Flush();
        fs.Position = 0;
        filecontent = fs.ToArray();
```