# C# iTextSharp Merge multiple pdf via byte array

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I am new to using iTextSharp and working with Pdf files in general, but I think I'm on the right track.

I iterate through a list of pdf files, convert them to bytes, and push all of the resulting bytes into a byte array.  From there I pass the byte array to concatAndAddContent() to merge all of the pdf's into a single large pdf.  Currently I'm just getting the last pdf in the list (they seem to be overwriting)

```
public static byte[] concatAndAddContent(List<byte[]> pdfByteContent)
    {
        byte[] allBytes;

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Document doc = new Document();
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);

            doc.SetPageSize(PageSize.LETTER);
            doc.Open();
            PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
            PdfImportedPage page;

            PdfReader reader;
            foreach (byte[] p in pdfByteContent)
            {
                reader = new PdfReader(p);
                int pages = reader.NumberOfPages;

                // loop over document pages
                for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
                {
                    doc.SetPageSize(PageSize.LETTER);
                    doc.NewPage();
                    page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
                    cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);

                }
            }

            doc.Close();
            allBytes = ms.GetBuffer();
            ms.Flush();
            ms.Dispose();
        }

        return allBytes;
    }
```

Above is the working code that results in a single pdf being created, and the rest of the files are being ignored.  Any suggestions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging multiple PDFs using iTextSharp in c#.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029142/merging-multiple-pdfs-using-itextsharp-in-c-net)

Comment: Are you sure that the pdfByteContent list contains more than byte array? Can we see the code you use to call the function?

Comment: I don't know if it solves your problem, but it does not seem like you need to Dispose and Flush. Your "using" block will automatically dispose when exited. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21230314/c-sharp-flushing-streamwriter-and-a-memorystream. The Flush method is overridden to do nothing for the MemoryStream class (it is inherited from the Stream class, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.flush(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Instead of allBytes = ms.GetBuffer(); try using allBytes = ms.ToArray(); The former method returns all data in the buffer, which may include uninitialized bytes / garbage. See the remarks of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer.aspx#remarksToggle

Comment: Without a doubt, as @KentMuntheCaspersen said, always use `ToArray()`, never use `GetBuffer()`.

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23063576/231316) which shows you how to iterate over a bunch of `PdfReader` objects and use a simple `AddDocument()` method so that you don't need to iterate over pages.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Not a duplicate - that question does not take a byte array as an argument.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Are there any methods within PdfReader that take a Byte Array?

Comment: @KentMuntheCaspersen Changed the ms.GetBuffer() to my.ToArray() - same result.

Comment: @confusedandamused, yes, you can pass a byte array to the constructor.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Do you have any example code for this?  I'm slightly confused by what you mean.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is pretty much just a C# version of [Bruno's code here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23063576/231316).

This is pretty much the simplest, safest and recommended way to merge PDF files. The `PdfSmartCopy` object is able to detect redundancies in the multiple files which can reduce file size some times. One of the overloads on it accepts a full `PdfReader` object which can be instantiated however you want.

```
public static byte[] concatAndAddContent(List<byte[]> pdfByteContent) {

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
        using (var doc = new Document()) {
            using (var copy = new PdfSmartCopy(doc, ms)) {
                doc.Open();

                //Loop through each byte array
                foreach (var p in pdfByteContent) {

                    //Create a PdfReader bound to that byte array
                    using (var reader = new PdfReader(p)) {

                        //Add the entire document instead of page-by-page
                        copy.AddDocument(reader);
                    }
                }

                doc.Close();
            }
        }

        //Return just before disposing
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: Testing this right now - I've never tried passing types within a using statement, and currently receive an error "Type used in a using statement must me implicitly convertible to SystemIDisposible"

Also where did you find documentation/use of copy.Adddocument() - it seems as though PdfSmartCopy doesn't contain a definition for it.

Comment: Are you using iTextSharp 4.1.6? If so this code won't work with that.

Comment: Ah I was on 4.x upgraded, and the function call worked.

Currently it still seems to be overwriting each pdf I'm passing in via the bytes - could this be due to how I am passing in the byte array?  

I'm essentially taking each pdf, turning them into bytes, and placing them all into a List<byte[]> (which happens to be pdfByteContent)

When calling File.WriteallBytes() each time I see the overwriting happening as well.

Comment: @ChrisHaas, could you take a look at this question about itextSharp? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45599357/tables-instead-of-columns-for-pdf-creation . Thank you so much in advance. I have a few questions that I would like clarified.

Comment: I'm seeing this does merge the pdfs together, but I lose any form fields in the AcroFields property of the document.  Trying to find a fix for that.  I'm use 5.x right now.

Comment: love respect thank you. you saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<byte[]> finallist= new List<byte[]>();
```

finallist.Add(concatAndAddContent(bytes));
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("path",finallist);

Comment: add information about your answer. code only answers will not be very clear

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).